# How do I perform mathematical operation linked with user input

Tags: visual-studio, vba, math

I want to be able to input a number and choose a variable then what the variable is set to then its subtracted by the number inputed and displayed in a TextBox when i click the calculate button (I'm trying to create a rank calculator for a game).
 [Current cR is TextBox1, Choosen Rank is ComboBox1 and Calculate is Button1]

The Template
 http://imgur.com/ofre43a

Comment: I would love to help more with this little project, but I need more details. What exactly do you mean when you say, "choose a variable"? Is it a math operator? What is the variable supposed to be set too? What is your overal all goal with this?

Comment: With this calculator im have to get a integer in order for me to give a estimate i will use the following equasion private1 = 1000 and ccr = current xp that your on agxp = average game xp i need to know how to code this (private1 - ccr / agxp = restimated games remaining.)

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will look something like this if I understand your equation correctly.

```
private1-textbox1.value/agxp = rgr
```

I think that is essentially what you are asking. I am assuming you will have assigned a value to private1 previously and that the ccr is inputed by the user. I also am assuming that your agxp is also previously assigned. There is the possibility that the value in textbox1 will be read as a string not as an integer. If that is the case, you will have to convert it to an integer.